# Using exponentiation **0.5 less efficient than math.sqrt?

Tags: python, exponentiation

A quote from "[Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Python-Programming-Introduction-Computer-Science/dp/1887902996)"

> We could have taken the square root
>   using exponentiation **. Using
>   math.sqrt is somewhat more efficient.

"Somewhat", but to what extent, and how?

Comment: You can always measure it yourself with `timeit`. For the record, `math.sqrt` is only roughly 5% faster for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Theoretically, [hammar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637589/using-exponentiation-less-efficient-than-math-sqrt/6637608#6637608) and [duffymo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637589/using-exponentiation-less-efficient-than-math-sqrt/6637620#6637620) are good guesses. But in practice, on my machine, it's *not* more efficient:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[n ** 0.5 for n in range(100)]', setup='import math', number=10000)
0.15518403053283691
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[math.sqrt(n) for n in range(100)]', setup='import math', number=10000)
0.17707490921020508
```

Part of the problem is the `.` operation. If you import `sqrt` directly into the namespace, you get a slight improvement.

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[sqrt(n) for n in range(100)]', setup='from math import sqrt', number=10000)
0.15312695503234863
```

Key word there: *slight*.

Further testing indicates that as the number gets larger, the benefit you get from using `sqrt` increases. But still not by a lot!

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[n ** 0.5 for n in range(1000000)]', setup='import math', number=1)
0.18888211250305176
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[math.sqrt(n) for n in range(1000000)]', setup='import math', number=1)
0.18425297737121582
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt='[sqrt(n) for n in range(1000000)]', setup='from math import sqrt', number=1)
0.1571958065032959
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusions.

Answer (score 11):

No need to guess the implementation, we can read the code!

`math.sqrt` is a thin wrapper about `sqrt` from the standard C library: see [`mathmodule.c`, line 956](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661195a92131/Modules/mathmodule.c#l956)

The `**` operator has multiple implementations depending on the types of the arguments, but in the case of a floating-point exponent, it eventually dispatches to `pow` from the standard C library (see [`floatobject.c` line 783](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/661195a92131/Objects/floatobject.c#l783)).

Modern CPUs often have special square root instructions which general exponentiation routines don't use (compare and contrast the implementations of [`pow`](http://codesearch.google.com/#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/releases/glibc-2.3.1.tar.bz2%7CQzvfrd4m2kQ/glibc-2.3.1/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_powl.S&q=pow&exact_package=ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/releases/glibc-2.3.1.tar.bz2) and [`sqrt`](http://codesearch.google.com/#xy1xtVWIKOQ/pub/glibc/releases/glibc-2.3.1.tar.bz2%7CQzvfrd4m2kQ/glibc-2.3.1/sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/e_sqrt.c&q=sqrt%20x86_64&exact_package=ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/glibc/releases/glibc-2.3.1.tar.bz2) in glibc for x86-64, for example). But once all the interpreter overhead is added (byte codes, type checking, method dispatch etc), the difference in raw speed doesn't matter all that much, and can be dominated by issues like whether you call `sqrt` directly or look it up via the `math` module (as shown by the timings in other answers).

Answer (score 1):

`**` has to support any exponent while `math.sqrt` knows it's always `0.5`. `math.sqrt` can therefore use a more specialized (and therefore probably more efficient) algorithm.

Comment: An optimal implementation of `**` could simply branch to `math.sqrt` if the exponent is smaller than 1. That would probably have a barely measurable impact.

Comment: @zneak: Most implementations *do*.

Comment: @zneak: Even so, it has to make that test, so it's always going to be (however slightly) slower.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that math.sqrt uses [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which converges quadratically, and exponentiation uses something else that is slower.

Comment: As also noted by zneak in a comment: There's no reason expotentiation shouldn't use the same algorithm, or simply reuse the existing implementation, for expotentiation by 0.5.

Comment: `math.sqrt` is probably an alias for the C math function `sqrt`, which is implemented using the best algorithm for your platform. If your CPU supports SSE instructions, you get an `sqrt*` instruction family, of which all members are as fast as can be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach. We want an int just bigger than the square root. Two ways (which disagree for square numbers but that's OK):

```
>>>timeit.timeit(stmt='[int(n**0.5)+1 for n in range(1000000)]', setup='', number=1)  
0.481772899628  
>>>timeit.timeit(stmt='[ceil(sqrt(n)) for n in range(1000000)]', setup='from math import sqrt, ceil', number=1)  
0.293844938278  
>>>timeit.timeit(stmt='[int(ceil(sqrt(n))) for n in range(1000000)]', setup='from math import sqrt, ceil', number=1)  
0.511347055435
```

So the math functions are faster...until you convert the float to int. (I need to do a lot of comparisons with the value, and while I haven't tested it, comparing integers should be cheaper than comparing floats.)

But hey, it's *Python*. You're on top of too many abstractions to try to optimize performance with this level of granularity.