# Generating large prime numbers in python

Tags: python, random, rsa, primality-test

I can't seem to make random prime numbers using this code, please can someone help me?

```
def RandomPrime():
  prime = False
  while prime == False:
    n = random.randint(10000, 100000)
    if n % 2 != 0:
      for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2):
        if n % x ==0:
          prime = False
        else:
          prime = True


  return n
```

Comment: On each iteration of the `for` loop, you're ignoring what the earlier iterations told you by setting `prime = False` or `prime = True` without considering what `prime` used to be.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine what happens if the *last* number in `range(3, int(n**0.5), 2)` is not an integer divisor of `n`:

```
if n % x ==0:
    prime = False # not this
else:
    prime = True # this
```

So *even if all previous checks evaluated `False`*, you call `n` a prime. The *minimal* change to your code to fix this is:

```
prime = prime and True # or 'prime &= True'
```

So if `prime` is *already* `False`, it remains `False`.

However, bear in mind that, for primality, if *any* of those checks is `False` `n` is not prime. You can use this and Python's `and` and `all` (which are evaluated lazily, i.e. don't keep checking once finding a `False`) to implement much more efficiently:

```
def rand_prime():
    while True:
        p = randint(10000, 100000)
        if (r % 2 != 0 and
            all(p % n != 0 for n in range(3, int(((p ** 0.5) + 1), 2))):
            return p
```

For even better performance, note that `randrange` incorporates a `step` argument, just like `range`, so you can skip all of the even numbers (which definitely aren't prime!):

```
def rand_prime():
    while True:
        p = randrange(10001, 100000, 2)
        if all(p % n != 0 for n in range(3, int((p ** 0.5) + 1), 2)):
            return p
```

*Note: `sqrt(n)` (from `math`) is, in my opinion, a little clearer to other, less-technical readers than `n ** 0.5` (although it [may or may not be more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637589/using-exponentiation-0-5-less-efficient-than-math-sqrt)).*

Comment: very nice answer. helpful

Answer (score 0):

Correct logic, you are setting `True` when `n % x` ! = `0` for first time:

```
  for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2):
    if n % x ==0:
      prime = False
    else:
      prime = True
```

should be:

```
  prime = False
  for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2):
    if n % x ==0:
      break
  else: 
    prime = True
```

Read [break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

The shorter way of writing equivalent code will be (from @[Steve Jesso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13005/steve-jessop)):

```
prime = all(n % x != 0 for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2)
```

Comment: The OP only wants to `return` once a prime is found, not `return False` - it should loop to a new random number.

Comment: The `else` of a `for` loop executes if the loop *doesn't* break, so you should set `prime = True` in there. But actually you can replace the whole thing with `prime = all(n % x != 0 for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes I corrected. also added your suggestion Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the tabs: The else should refer to the whole for loop, not to the iF

```
def RandomPrime():
  prime = False
  while prime == False:
    n = random.randint(10000, 100000)
    if n % 2 != 0:
      for x in range(3, int(n**0.5), 2):
        if n % x ==0:
          break
      else:
          prime = True


  return n
```

Comment: Considering that the loop doesn't even have a `break` in it, this is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There're errors in your code:

1. Incorrect "else:"; you can't declare number being prime if a remainder is not 0;
   *All the remaiders* should be non-zeros
2. int(n**0.5) should be int(n**0.5 + 1) to prevent round-up errors

The possible solution is

```
def RandomPrime():
  while True:
    n = random.randint(10000, 100000)

    if n % 2 == 0:
      continue;

    prime = True;

    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5 + 1), 2):
      if n % x == 0:
        prime = False;

        break; 

    if prime: 
      return n
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating large random numbers over and over can cost a lot of time. For this reason I chose one random number, then incremented it until a prime number was found.

```py
import random

def generate_big_prime(size:int):
    p = random.randrange(2 ** (size - 1), 2 ** size - 1)
    if p % 2 == 0:
        p += 1
    while not is_prime(p):
        p += 2
    return p
```

Where `size` is the number of bits desired and `is_prime(n:int)` is a primality test.

Since testing the primality can be very slow, again especially for large numbers, I would recommend the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) for its efficiency.