# Random prime Number in python

Tags: python, random, generator, list-comprehension, primes

I currently have ↓ set as my `randprime(p,q)` function. Is there any way to condense this, via something like a **genexp** or **listcomp**? Here's my function:

```
n = randint(p, q)
while not isPrime(n):
    n = randint(p, q)
```

Comment: It seems like it would better to generate a list of primes between `p` and `q` and then choose a random one from that list.

Comment: You can increase your chances of a number being prime by setting the lowest bit to 1, thereby making it odd - there is only one even prime, which is 2. In fact, all prime numbers other than 2 and 3 are either one below, or one above a multiple of six.

Comment: I hate when someone downvote a question without telling why because the OP can't fix it if he does not know what is wrong.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, that depends on the size of p & q. For large numbers, this would be more efficient. Also, if you're doing a number sieve (easiest way of generating primes), then you need to start at 1.

Comment: almost the same stuff http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043075/generating-large-prime-numbers-in-python

Comment: What would improve this is to define a generator which will give you random integers in the interval from `p` to `q` without replacement.  But I can't find a good way to do that.

Comment: @Joel That's what Hunter McMillen's comment describes.

Comment: Please folks, the question lacks specificity and much of the back-and-forth here results from that. Could you please blame that instead of other answerers?

Comment: @Joel, you are right on this, and I have removed my earlier comment.

Comment: Anyways - PolarBear: as you can tell, it's a really interesting question.  Lots of challenging things going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to just generate the list of primes, and then choose from that line.
As is, with your code there is the slim chance that it will hit an infinite loop, either if there are no primes in the interval or if `randint` always picks a non-prime then the `while` loop will never end.

So this is probably shorter and less troublesome:

```
import random
primes = [i for i in range(p,q) if isPrime(i)]
n = random.choice(primes)
```

The other advantage of this is there is no chance of deadlock if there are no primes in the interval. As stated this can be slow depending on the range, so it would be quicker if you cached the primes ahead of time:

```
# initialising primes
minPrime = 0
maxPrime = 1000
cached_primes = [i for i in range(minPrime,maxPrime) if isPrime(i)]

#elsewhere in the code
import random
n = random.choice([i for i in cached_primes if p<i<q])
```

Again, further optimisations are possible, but are very much dependant on your actual code... and you know what they say about premature optimisations.

Comment: This can be a very bad idea if p and q are of the order 10**10, which is a reasonable thing to try if you're thinking about encryption.

Comment: I guess that if there are any primes between `p` and `q` it will deadlock for sure.

Comment: Well, presumably they'd be caching the `isPrime` check, or have a prebuilt list to work from.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - not necessarily. When working with large primes (e.g. for RSA encryption), the usual way is to check small numbers, and then use a statistical method - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests (since a full test would take way too years for a 2048-bit prime) - each test run on a prime will succeed, and each test run on a non-prime has a 50% chance of showing that the number is non-prime. Decide how low a probability you want, and run the appropriate number of tests.

Comment: People are just making wild assumptions about encryption and crazy large numbers. This might be an undergrad first-year programming question.

Comment: Setting aside the issue of whether this will work well if the range from `p` to `q` is large, this code still has a bug if `p=14`, `q=16`.  It will return `random.choice([])` which causes an `IndexError`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script written in python to generate n random prime integers between tow given integers:

```
import numpy as np

def getRandomPrimeInteger(bounds):

    for i in range(bounds.__len__()-1):
        if bounds[i + 1] > bounds[i]:
            x = bounds[i] + np.random.randint(bounds[i+1]-bounds[i])
            if isPrime(x):
                return x

        else:
            if isPrime(bounds[i]):
                return bounds[i]

        if isPrime(bounds[i + 1]):
            return bounds[i + 1]

    newBounds = [0 for i in range(2*bounds.__len__() - 1)]
    newBounds[0] = bounds[0]
    for i in range(1, bounds.__len__()):
        newBounds[2*i-1] = int((bounds[i-1] + bounds[i])/2)
        newBounds[2*i] = bounds[i]

    return getRandomPrimeInteger(newBounds)

def isPrime(x):
    count = 0
    for i in range(int(x/2)):
        if x % (i+1) == 0:
            count = count+1
    return count == 1



#ex: get 50 random prime integers between 100 and 10000:
bounds = [100, 10000]
for i in range(50):
    x = getRandomPrimeInteger(bounds)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it would be great if you could use an iterator to give the integers from p to q in random order (without replacement).  I haven't been able to find a way to do that.  The following will give random integers in that range and will skip anything that it's tested already.

```
import random
fail = False
tested = set([])
n = random.randint(p,q)
while not isPrime(n):
    tested.add(n)
    if len(tested) == p-q+1:
        fail = True
        break
    while n in s:
        n = random.randint(p,q)

if fail:
    print 'I failed'
else:
    print n, ' is prime'
```

The big advantage of this is that if say the range you're testing is just (14,15), your code would run forever.  This code is guaranteed to produce an answer if such a prime exists, and tell you there isn't one if such a prime does not exist.  You can obviously make this more compact, but I'm trying to show the logic.

Comment: Yes, but mine will finish if given a range without a prime, and run in significantly less time if given a range with only a few primes.

Comment: code from OP is 3 lines but it will deadlock if there is no primes between p and q so it is unsafe.

Comment: It was me, and I voted you down because your answer, while introducing something useful, is the EXACT OPPOSITE of what was being asked - `Is there any way to condense this`. I did give credit that that part wasn't mine. It wasn't the basis of my answer, only a footnote. You are welcome to incorporate my code into your answer as a footnote (or ideas therefrom).

Comment: @AMADANONInc. Fine - your code is one line, but it's still nearly 2 times as many characters as the original code, requires importing itertools, and doesn't solve the bug.  Is that condensed?  Take out the bit of my code eliminating the bug and my code is basically the same length (in characters) as yours.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr but it won't finish in reasonable time if the range of integers is very large (which is usually when people are trying to generate random prime numbers).  This is why RSA encryption works.

Comment: Again, if they are trying to get a random prime number its probably best if they work from an existing set or cache the results. Its really not worth checking if 17 is a prime every time you go through - you know its a prime the first time.

Comment: Caching is what I'm doing by having the set `tested` (it's not worth checking 18 isn't prime every time).  I agree your code will work, and may well be good for some cases. My issue with your answer is that working from an existing set is impossible for large ranges because we don't know what that set is and finding the set takes forever. This is why encryption works.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr  Actually, your code breaks for p=14, q=15.  You end up with random.choice([]).  Easily fixed.

Answer (score -1):

```
next(i for i in itertools.imap(lambda x: random.randint(p,q)|1,itertools.count()) if isPrime(i))
```

This starts with itertools.count() - this gives an infinite set.

Each number is mapped to a new random number in the range, by itertools.imap(). imap is like map, but returns an iterator, rather than a list - we don't want to generate a list of inifinite random numbers!

Then, the first matching number is found, and returned.

Works efficiently, even if p and q are very far apart - e.g. 1 and 10**30, which generating a full list won't do!

By the way, this is not more efficient than your code above, and is a lot more difficult to understand at a glance - please have some consideration for the next programmer to have to read your code, and just do it as you did above. That programmer might be you in six months, when you've forgotten what this code was supposed to do!

P.S - in practice, you might want to replace count() with xrange (NOT range!) e.g. `xrange((p-q)**1.5+20)` to do no more than that number of attempts (balanced between limited tests for small ranges and large ranges, and has no more than 1/2% chance of failing if it could succeed), otherwise, as was suggested in another post, you might loop forever.

PPS - improvement: replaced `random.randint(p,q)` with `random.randint(p,q)|1` - this makes the code twice as efficient, but eliminates the possibility that the result will be 2.

Comment: I considered q-p, and then simplified to p, and then `p**2`. My latest answer (just decided) is (q-p)**2. q-p is probably not enough; If you have two numbers and one of them is a prime (e.g. q=18 and p=19), then you have a 25% chance of failure. As the range increases, the chances of covering all numbers in the range decreases (sampling `range` random numbers in `range`).

Comment: Having done some hunting, a very bad case scenario is choosing p=1425172824437699411, and q=p+1475; in that range of numbers, there is only one prime (and 1475 non-primes). Each one has a 1475/1476 chance of being a non-prime, so even 1476 attempts has a 37% chance of failing.

Comment: Another calculation shows that `(q-p)**2` attempts may not be enough - for q=p+1 (where p or q is prime), there's a 6% chance of failure for that many (=4) tests. I will revise my answer to `(q-p)**2+20`, which will only be slightly slower, and work better for small numbers.